# How to sort a Set by its Id of a @ManyToMany relation?

Tags: java, sorting, spring-data-jpa, set, many-to-many

I would like to sort a Set by its Id of a @ManyToMany relation in a web application that I am developing and I don't know how to do it. At the moment the Set is displayed in the order in which the ManyToMany relationships were created.

**Class Especie**

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Especie extends Familia{

    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer diasGerminacionDesde;
    private Integer diasGerminacionHasta;

    @ManyToOne
    private Familia familia;

    @JoinTable(
        name = "especie_mesesSiembra"
        ,joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="especie_id")
        ,inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="mesSiembra_id")
    )

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<MesSiembra> mesesSiembra;
}
```

**Class EspecieControlador (Controller)**

```
@GetMapping
public List<Especie> listarTodos() {
    return servicio.listarTodos();
}
```

**Class EspecieServicio (Service)**

```
public List<Especie> listarTodos() {
    Sort orden = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "nombre");
    return repositorio.findAll(orden);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LinkedHashSet + JPA annotation @OrderBy

```
@OrderBy
private Set<MesSiembra> mesesSiembra = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: If I put the code in the following way, I have a mapping error.
`@ManyToMany
 @OrderBy("mesSiembra_id")
    private Set<MesSiembra> mesesSiembra= new LinkedHashSet<>();`

Comment: actually you can replace @OrderBy("mesSiembra_id")  by @OrderBy. What is the error ?

Comment: There it has worked for me with @OrderBy only without putting anything in parentheses. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, I updated my answer that you can accept it. Thanks !